# Generic allows wrong types

Tags: java, generics

I have a custom class `ListA`

```
public class ListA<T> { ... }
```

with a method insert

```
public void insert(T value) {
    array[0] = value;
}
```

and I create my `ListA` like this:

```
ListA list = null;
list = new ListA<Integer>();
```

Why can I add Strings to the list?

```
list.insert("abc");
```

works just fine, and if I print it I can see `abc`. Is there a way to disallow every type except the one I put in `<>` like `<Integer>`?

Comment: You declared `ListA list` instead of `ListA<Integer> list`. You've lost the generic type information that tells the compiler only to allow that particular type.

Comment: Yup, this is just a typo.

Comment: I have an if whether someone wants to create an Integer list, a Double list, a Char list or whatever they want, so I can't do ListA<Type> list

Comment: Your compiler will have issued you a warning about using raw types - please pay attention to it.

Comment: That means you have type knowledge only at run-time, and not at compile-time.  So the compiler can't help you enforce it.

Comment: But if I declare my list as ListA<Integer> list = new ListA<Integer>(); I can't use my insert method for other types than Integer?

Comment: @besplash That's right. That's what you've written: `ListA` has a generic type `T`, and `insert` accepts an argument of type `T`. You've just missed the generic type off your variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are quick bytes to try to add little more to your generic knowledge, which will solve your problem:

This `ListA list = null;` is nothing but you are saying `list` is a variable of type `ListA`. Now since you have created your class as a "**generic type**" `public class ListA<T>` i.e. using "**type parameter**" so whenever you say `ListA list = null;` then it becomes a "**raw type**", if you had created your class without any type parameter i.e. like this `public class ListA` then if you do `ListA list = null;` then it would NOT be called as "raw type" and would be considered simple type declaration because your class is not a generic type.

Now, this `list = new ListA<Integer>();` is nothing but you are creating a "**parameterized type**" object and assigning it `list`, which is a raw type, so as @JonSkeet has already commented that your compiler will give you a warning, unless you are suppressing the warnings using **`-Xlint:-unchecked`** flag.

Now, you are able to do `list.insert("abc");` because your `list` ORV is a raw type, **recall the important fact that at compile time compiler checks the variable type to decide which all methods you can call on ORV and whether you are breaking type safety or not**. Now, since `list` ORV is a raw type so even `list.insert(new MyClass());` will be allowed, basically you can put any object, because `public class ListA<T>` means ListA could be of any type which is sybtype of Object. `public class ListA<T>` is as good as saying `public class ListA<T extends Object>`

From one of the comments to your question it looks like you are looking for **[bounded parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)**, so if you want that you should be able to insert any type which is subtype of `Number` then you should say `public class ListA<T extends Number>`. If you are looking to insert numbers as well as string, then what is happening in your case is expected, because even with `public class ListA<T extends Number>` you cannot insert string or any other type which is not subtype of `Number`

I would recommend reading bounded parameter link I have provided, for in-depth knowledge.

Comment: This is all quite a long-winded way of saying that (1) `ListA<T>` is equivalent to `ListA<T extends Object>`, and (2) given `Foo<T extends U>` then `new Foo` is basically equivalent to `new Foo<U>`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I still remember starting my education from nursery, then to primary school to secondary school to graduation. Gotta take steps one by one, moving higher and higher, in the end reaching what's needed.

Comment: @hagrawal Thanks a lot! I guess I got it right now. I thought, that you would assign a type by using `= ListA<Integer>();` too.

Comment: @besplash Cool.